# HTML jquery response is cached on IE

Tags: javascript, html, caching, jquery

Well I have a very rough version of gomoku working now.
I'm using Jquery, Php and mysql database.

When a user clicks on a board square a piece is placed.  An ajax refresh determines if turn count has been incremented and updates the board's html if necessary.

The problem is that Internet Explore (6,8,&probably 7) caches the page on the first visit.  Even if the page is refresh manually the cached content will remain.

I tried using

```
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

on the html page with no luck.  Only way to get an update is to delete the files though the tools.

I hope this is enough information.  If not I'll try to answer questions as best as possible.

---

**Update 3**
I got it working I used the .ajaxSetup
Thanks phoenix, tim, and everyone else.

Comment: You can also set the headers of the page you are requesting not to cache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each time append a random number to the end of the AJAX request to make the request URL to be different.

The random bit of information you will submit to the server can be a number (larger the better), random string, or a timestamp.

```
var url = “http://domain?myParameters=values&pseudoParam= "+new Date().getTime();
```

Edit:

If you want to set up **global settings** for AJAX requests then you can use

[jQuery.ajaxSetup( options )](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajaxSetup)

and to set cache off

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

For each request you can use

[jQuery.ajax( options )](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#toptions)

and set the cache to false as pointed out by @Tim

Comment: do i put the ajaxSetup function in my script anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

you could try "cache: false"

```
$.ajax({url: "url", success: myCallback, cache: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a default IE behaviour. I avoided that by adding random number in the request.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found it out:

jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });